# GMail Chrome extension: new compose email design

Tags: email, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm developing the Chrome extension for GMail that should read/update the composed email recipients.
Not so long ago I discovered that the Google switched some email accounts to the new "cool" design.
In the old design it was pretty simple to update the recipients - `$('textarea[name="to"]').val("xxx")`
By the new design it is complicated and requires to emulate multiple UI clicks:
[image]

Does anyone has idea how to deal with it?